# NestJS compiling without errors but VScode showing error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, nestjs

When I build the NestJS application inside a docker container with docker-compose, it builds without any errors. But the VS-code file explorer is showing all my files have errors with missing modules. Please refer to screen shots as below:

[image]

[image]

Please help.

Comment: do `npm install` then restart vscode.

Comment: @omidh did that multiple times. `docker-compose` does that for me. Here is what my dockerfile looks like - 

```FROM node:14
WORKDIR /new_shop
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .```

Comment: docker is isolated from you local workplace. do `npm install`  from vscode terminal.

Comment: Delete the dist directory and run again with: 
npm run start:dev

Comment: I ran `npm install` in the src folder and it worked thanks @omidh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't run `npm i` or the yarn equivalent, node modules folder is not populated with the actual node packages/files.

Keep in mind that as @omidh said in his comment, when you run the docker command, you make an isolate environment/container with your code and all node_modules installed correctly. That means that your code is copied inside the container, then **inside** the container the command `npm install` is being run and your code is compiled/run eventually.

So that is the reason that your container runs without any error and your editor is showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i just need to run "npm run lint" to lint and autofix with eslint as stated in nest js official site.